# Constraining columns with each other in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I'm learning MSBI tools and came across a requirement in SSRS wherein we need to constrain report parameter 2 with parameter 1.
i.e. if I have parameters setup on [AdventureWorks2008R2].[HumanResources].[Department] table and if I select **"Group Name" (Parameter 1)** as **"Manufacturing"** then the **"Name" (Parameter 2)** drop down should populate only relevant values(**"Production"** and **"Production Control"**) specific to selected parameter 1 value **("Manufacturing")**

I have been exposed to OBIEE tool and know that under this tool we have a **"constrain"** option under Prompts to achieve the same.

I could come up with the following solution under SSRS: 
Created two datasets for each of the parameters with below queries.

Parameter 1 (GroupName)

```
 SELECT DISTINCT GroupName
    FROM            HumanResources.Department
```

Parameter 2 (DeptName)

```
SELECT        Name
FROM            HumanResources.Department
WHERE        (GroupName = @GroupName)
```

This worked. However if there are 5 such parameters which are to be constrained then with this solution I would have to create 5 such datasets and accordingly build the WHERE clause for each parameter.
Is there a better solution to achieve the same (there should be..)

I'm new to SSRS and therefore would appreciate any pointers here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is called "Cascading Parameters" and they are implemented exactly as you did. You can read about them here:
[Adding Cascading Parameters (SSRS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx)

So if you need to implement 5 of such parameters you have to write 5 queries for 5 datasets each one containing WHERE referencing parameter defined in previous dataset

Comment: Thanks sepupic. So is this the best solution we have got? The last parameter dataset would need to have all earlier parameters in the WHERE  clause. This doesn't look that elegant.

Comment: The query for the last parameter would only need to reference the parameter it depends on, that might mean all previous ones, or just a single one depending on your requirements.

If we extend you example (with some made up tables) and say we've made DeptName a multi-value parameter and then we want to get a list of Employees for our final parameter then the Employee parameter query would be something like `SELECT FirstName + ' ' + Lastname FROM Employees WHERE Department IN (@DeptName)` Note that SSRS will split the values from @DeptName and injectthem into the IN clause as comma separated